# Prove $[(n, k)] = 7^{*} \iff n - k = 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, relations, solution-verification, equivalence-relations, peano-axioms

> Prove $[(n, k)] = 7^{*} \iff n - k = 7$ given $7^{*} = [(8,1)] \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k < n \in \mathbb{N}$ using any facts about addition in the Peano System.

$k < n \in \mathbb{N}$ is defined as $n = k + m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. For $k < n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n - k$ is defined as the $m$ such that $n = k + m$ (i.e. $n = k + (n - k)$. The equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ whose equivalence classes are integers is defined as $(n, k) \sim (n', k')$ if $n + k' = n' + k$. Also, $(n, k) \sim (n', k') \iff [(n,k)] = [(n', k')]$.

For the $\leftarrow$ direction, we have to show that $7^{*} = [(8,1)] = [(n,k)]$, assuming $n - k = 7$. By the definition of subtraction in $\mathbb{N}$, we have $n = k + 7$. We can substitute this value of $n$ into $[(n, k)]$ so we have $[(k + 7, k)]$. If we can show $(k + 7, k) \sim (8,1)$ then we can use the fact that $(n, k) \sim (n', k') \iff [(n,k)] = [(n', k')]$ to show that $[(n,k)] = [(8,1)]$. So using the definition of $\sim$, we have $(k + 7) + 1 = k + 8$ so we have $k + 8 = k + 8$, and thus $\sim$, and thus $[(n,k)] = [(8,1)]$.

For the $\rightarrow$ direction, we suppose that $[(n, k)] = 7^{*} = [(8,1)]$, and want to prove that $n - k = 7$. By the definition of subtraction in $\mathbb{N}$, it's the same thing as proving that $n = k + 7$. We are also given in the problem that $k < n$, so we know by definition of subtraction that $n = k + m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If we can prove $m = 7$, then we are done. We know that $n = 8$ and $k = 1$, so we have $8 = 1 + m$. This is the same as $1 + 7 = 1 + m$, so by cancellation we have $7 = m$. But this is incorrect (as per professor). What have I done incorrectly in the proof?

Comment: @GitGud: Elementary set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Elementary properties of integers constructed from the natural numbers, is it not the first few pages in every elementary set theory book? Don't let me stop you from removing the tag.